# Qual a diferença entre «Comemorar» e «Celebrar»?

Tags: significado, gramática, significado-em-contexto

Percebi que os dois significam "*to celebrate*".

Mas serão diferentes? Existe alguma preferência para os usar de maneiras diferentes, ou usar algum deles só em lugares especiais?

Comment: Fora 'comemorar' ser um pouco mais coloquial que 'celebrar', que pode conferir um pouco mais de gravidade à frase, me parecem sinônimos.

Comment: @stafusa, mas não é exatamente essa a pergunta? São sinónimos, até porque traduzem ambos para "*to celebrate*"; mas têm algumas nuances de diferenças, porque não são perfeitamente substituíveis. (Não celebrarias o [Remembrance Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_Day), que é só comemorado.)

Comment: @ANeves Sim, meu comentário é em parte uma resposta parcial, sem fontes ou outro suporte - por esses defeitos, não postei como resposta. Mas eu não veria problema em usar "celebrar" com o Dia da Lembrança, pelo contrário: como vejo "celebrar" como mais formal, penso que ele se presta mais facilmente ao uso. Perceba que pode haver uma diferença entre pt-BR e pt-PT aqui, no Brasil, "[comemorar](http://www.aulete.com.br/comemorar)" é frequentemente usado no sentido de festejar, portanto distante do caráter sério do inglês *commemorate*, talvez não seja o caso em Portugal.

Comment: @ANeves Agora que justifiquei a afirmação, terminei de escrever e postei como resposta. :) Acho que um complemento cobrindo o pt-PT seria uma ótima adição.

Comment: Boa cena, @stafusa :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu diria que, no português brasileiro, "comemorar" é um pouco mais coloquial que "celebrar".

Porque, em pt-BR, "comemorar" é usado com muita frequência com o sentido de "festejar" (como em "comemorar um gol", "comemorar o nascimento da filha"), e.g., o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/comemorar) coloca como primeiro sentido:

> 1. Celebrar com festa, festejar (data, acontecimento ou ocasião especial): comemorar um aniversário.

E mais raramente com um sentido mais solene, de recordação:

> 2. Solenizar a recordação de: O documentário e o ciclo de palestras comemoraram o grande compositor.
> 3. Trazer à memória, fazer recordar; lembrar: Este monumento comemora o fim da escravidão.

que são sentidos mais próximos ao do inglês [*to commemorate*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/commemorate):

> To honor the memory of (a person or event, for example), especially with a ceremony.

Já "celebrar" é essencialmente um sinônimo de "comemorar" nesses contextos, mas com outros significados (ver abaixo) que fazem com que a palavra se encontre mais frequentemente usada em contextos formais.

> 3. Louvar, exaltar, enaltecer. [td. : Camões celebra os feitos de Vasco da Gama.]
> 4. Realizar (algo, ger. envolvendo algum tipo de promessa, compromisso, aliança) com as devidas formalidades ou com solenidade [td. : celebrar um casamento: O presidente celebra hoje o acordo comercial.]
> 5. Rezar ou dizer (missa).

Comment: É, em Portugal acho que "comemorar" é mais solene, e embora possa incluir gala não inclui festa. O Priberam diz «[1. Lembrar. 2. Trazer à memória. 3. Solenizar, recordando.](https://dicionario.priberam.org/comemorar)». Sim, acho que um de nós os tugas podia explorar uma resposta com esta perspetiva. :)